# python split string into strings with same language characters

Tags: python, string, split, non-english

I want split strings like `"hiسلامaliعلی"` into `["hi", "سلام", "ali", "علی"]`.

the initial string contains only english and persian characters (with or without space) and I want to split it into continues same language characters.

is there an easy way to extract continues english character from string and split remaingin characters?

Comment: What about the Latin range? ASCII + accents?

Comment: by english characters I mean Latin range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split on ASCII letters with `re.split()`:

```
re.split(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', inputstring)
```

Demo with Python 3:

```
>>> inputstring = "hiسلامaliعلی"
>>> re.split(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', inputstring)
['', 'hi', 'سلام', 'ali', 'علی']
```

Extending this to the full Latin-1 range:

```
re.split(r'([a-zA-Z\xC0-\xFF]+)', inputstring)
```

For Python 2, do make sure you use `unicode` strings and prefix the regular expression with `u`:

```
re.split(ur'([a-zA-Z\xC0-\xFF]+)', inputstring)
```

In all cases, if the Latin text is at the start or end, an empty string is inserted as the string is split; you can remove these with:

```
result = [s for s in re.split(r'([a-zA-Z\xC0-\xFF]+)', inputstring) if s]
```

Comment: thanks. but it remains an empty string at start:

['', 'hi', '\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85', 'ali', '\xd8\xb9\xd9\x84\xdb\x8c']

Comment: @Ali: Yes, that's an artifact of using `re.split()`.

Comment: can I be sure the first string is always empty?

Comment: @Ali: only if the first character of the input string is a latin character. If the *last* character is a latin character you'll also get an empty string at the end.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters: In extended version non english words are splited inot charactes. I think you shoud use big X: re.split(ur'([a-zA-Z\XC0-\XFF]+)', inputstring)

Comment: @Ali: `\XC0` is not an escape, actually

Comment: @Ali: `[a-zA-Z\XC0-\XFF]` is the same thing as `[a-zA-Z0-\\]`; you are including all digits, plus some punctuation.

Comment: @Ali: I suspect you are instead using *byte strings in Python 2*; decode your byte string to Unicode first.